# Open Android application from FB post

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-opengraph

I am posting to FB from my app and need the "receiver" to be able to click the link in FB on their mobile and go to the app or the download page.
I have followed the instructions as far as I can see but nothing happens.

I am using a ShareActionProvider with type text/plain and the EXTRA_TEXT set to a url which is my link URL as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">

<HEAD>
  <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <TITLE></TITLE>
    <meta property="al:android:url" content="cardflip://story/1234">
    <meta property="al:android:package" content="il.co.anykey.games.cardflip">
    <meta property="al:android:app_name" content="CardFlip"/>
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://anykey.co.il/apps/cardflip/facebook-share.html"/>
    <meta property="og:title" content="Card Flip" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="Text Message" id="message"/>
    <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://anykey.co.il/apps/cardflip/feature.png" />
    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="****************" />
  <STYLE TYPE="text/css">
    body{font-family:Verdana,Geneva,sans-serif;font-size:16px;line-height:1.4em;color:#333;background-color:White;}
  </STYLE>
  <script>
      document.getElementById("message").setAttribute("content", getContent());
      function getContent() {
          return "This is a test";
      }
  </script>
</HEAD>
<BODY>

<A><IMG SRC="http://anykey.co.il/apps/cardflip/feature.png"></A>
<H1></H1>

<HR>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

It posts to FB but when I click on it all it does is open the picture.

What am I missing?

Comment: Implementation looks correct, Facebook debug tool seems to be able to read all of that properly. Did you make a post _after_ you added those meta tags and refreshed Facebook’s cache?

Comment: I haven't changed them at all. This is my original version. I could try a refresh and see what happens. What is the refresh link?

Comment: Sending a URL through the debugger clears the cache, https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ Be aware though that this does not affect already existing posts on Facebook retroactively, you might need to make a new post or refresh the share attachment on the existing one, before this shows any effect.

Comment: Ok. So did that and no help. Still when I click the link in FB mobile it just open up the pic.

Comment: Just tested it myself, only got redirected to the website as well. (I am using Facebook Lite on Android though, but I think it should still work in there.) I am not aware of any time delay before this takes effect, refreshing the cache using the debug tool should be all that’s necessary. Suggest you file a bug report and ask Facebook what is going wrong, https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/

Comment: Ok. I'll give it a little more time here and then head of there.

Comment: it might sound like a silly question but I believe that you already have set up deep links for android app right?. Also I would say that since you put the link in img tags then of course it opens it like an image because it is an image. Try to put the `<a href>` inside. You have only declared `<a>` without reference. Try to `<a href="http://anykey.co.il/apps/cardflip/feature.png">your image here</a>`